# Warning from iOS "Do not add subviews directly to the visual effect view itself"

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiview, subview, ios11

I have a function below and when I link with the iOS 11 SDK, I get an error:

> Do not add subviews directly to the visual effect view itself, instead add them to the -contentView.

The problem can be solved by changing

```
let effectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: UIBlurEffect(style: .dark))"
```

to

```
effectView = UIView()
```

but the effect is not present that way. How can I keep using `UIVisualEffectView` instead of `UIView`? I want to keep the effect.

```
let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
let messageFrame = UIView()
var activityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView()
var strLabel = UILabel()    
let effectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: UIBlurEffect(style: .dark))

func activityIndicator(_ title: String) {  
    strLabel.removeFromSuperview()
    activityIndicator.removeFromSuperview()
    effectView.removeFromSuperview()

    strLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 50, y: 0, width: 160, height: 46))
    strLabel.text = title
    strLabel.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14, weight: UIFont.Weight.medium)
    strLabel.textColor = UIColor(white: 0.9, alpha: 0.7)

    effectView.frame = CGRect(x: (view.frame.midX - strLabel.frame.width/2), y: (view.frame.midY - strLabel.frame.height/2), width: 160, height: 46)
    effectView.layer.cornerRadius = 15
    effectView.layer.masksToBounds = true

    activityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView(activityIndicatorStyle: .white)
    activityIndicator.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 46, height: 46)
    activityIndicator.startAnimating()

    effectView.addSubview(activityIndicator)
    effectView.addSubview(strLabel)
    view.addSubview(effectView)
}
```

Answer (score 12):

Just follow what the error says and add your subviews to `UIVisualEffectView`'s `contentView`.

```
effectView.contentView.addSubview(activityIndicator)
effectView.contentView.addSubview(strLabel)
```

Answer (score 6):

Apple says that;

> Depending on the desired effect, the effect may affect content layered
>   behind the view or content added to the visual effect view’s
>   contentView. Apply a visual effect view to an existing view and then
>   apply a UIBlurEffect or UIVibrancyEffect object to apply a blur or
>   vibrancy effect to the existing view. After you add the visual effect
>   view to the view hierarchy, add any subviews to the contentView
>   property of the visual effect view. **Do not add subviews directly to
>   the visual effect view itself**.

So, as per @the4kman add your subviews to content view of visual effect view

```
 effectView.contentView.addSubview(activityIndicator)
 effectView.contentView.addSubview(strLabel)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let messageFrame = UIView()
var activityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView()
var strLabel = UILabel()
effectView = UIView()

   func activityIndicator(_ title: String) {

    strLabel.removeFromSuperview()
    activityIndicator.removeFromSuperview()
    effectView.removeFromSuperview()

    strLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 50, y: 0, width: 160, height: 46))
    strLabel.text = title
    strLabel.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14, weight: UIFontWeightMedium)
    strLabel.textColor = UIColor(white: 0.9, alpha: 0.7)

    effectView.frame = CGRect(x: view.frame.midX - strLabel.frame.width/2, y: view.frame.midY - strLabel.frame.height/2 , width: 160, height: 46)
    effectView.layer.cornerRadius = 15
    effectView.layer.masksToBounds = true

    activityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView(activityIndicatorStyle: .white)
    activityIndicator.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 46, height: 46)
    activityIndicator.startAnimating()

    effectView.addSubview(activityIndicator)
    effectView.addSubview(strLabel)
    view.addSubview(effectView)
}
```

when start :

```
     activityIndicator("Your Text")
```

when Finished :

```
    self.effectView.removeFromSuperview()
```